# Permission class method def has_object_permission is not called

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

The problem is any user is able to delete the comment created by the other user, even i created and added the custom permission.py file, i also checked that def has_object_permission method is not running i tried to print "print statement" on terminal.
I want that only owner of comment can delete it's own comment and owner of the Post can delete anyone's comment.
**my view:**

```
    class CommentPostApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView, generics.DestroyAPIView,generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CommentPostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsCommentOwnerOrPostOwner]
    def get_queryset(self):
        post_id = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
        return models.CommentPost.objects.filter(post__pk=post_id, reply_to_comment__isnull=True)

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_id = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
        parent_comment_id = self.kwargs.get('parent_comment_id')
        user = self.request.user
        content = request.data.get('content')

        try:
            post = models.PicPost.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=post_id)

            if parent_comment_id is not None:
                reply_to_comment = models.CommentPost.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=parent_comment_id)
                comment_post = models.CommentPost(post=post, commenter=user, content=content, reply_to_comment=reply_to_comment)
            else:
                comment_post = models.CommentPost(post=post, commenter=user, content=content)
            
            comment_post.save()
            models.PicPost.objects.filter(pk=post_id).update(comments_count=F('comments_count')+1)
        except models.PicPost.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError("Post does not exist.")
        except models.CommentPost.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError("Parent comment does not exist.")

        return Response({"detail": "Comment added successfully."}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    
    @transaction.atomic
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        comment_id = self.kwargs.get('parent_comment_id')

        try:
            comment = models.CommentPost.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=comment_id)
            post_id = comment.post.id
            comment.delete()
            models.PicPost.objects.filter(pk=post_id).update(comments_count=F('comments_count')-1)
        except models.CommentPost.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError("This comment does not exists")
        return Response({"detail": "Comment deleted successfully."}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

```
**Custom Permission file**
```

```
    class IsCommentOwnerOrPostOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """Allow owners of comment, reply or post to delete them"""

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("Checking permissions for user:", request.user)
        print("Comment owner:", obj.commenter)
        print("Post owner:", obj.post.user)
        return request.user == obj.commenter or obj.post.user == request.user
```

```
**urls.py**
```

```
    path('post-comment/<int:post_id>/', views.CommentPostApiView.as_view(), name='add_top_level_comment'),
    path('post-comment/<int:post_id>/<int:parent_comment_id>/', views.CommentPostApiView.as_view(), name='add_reply_to_comment'),
```

Answer (score 1):

From [django rest framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissionsoranonreadonly)

**DjangoObjectPermissions**

This permission class ties into Django's standard [object permissions framework][objectpermissions] that allows per-object permissions on models.  **In order to use this permission class, you'll also need to add a permission backend that supports object-level permissions, such as [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian).**